# Async Data Publisher Error

Tags: wso2-api-manager

My WSO2 API Manager is logging continuously below logs. How to resolve this.

[2016-06-10 02:12:47,630] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for for tcp://localhost:7612
[2016-06-10 02:13:17,852] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for for tcp://localhost:7612
[2016-06-10 02:13:47,798] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for for tcp://localhost:7612

Comment: Did you configure API analytics as explained below? Did you have a working setup before this occurred?

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics

Comment: Yes, You are right, I configured the DAS and it was not up. Sooner it is up, the logging stopped.